# How to change the size of an SVG via CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to customize the size of my circle svg, however, when I set the font-size to 300px, the size of the svg does not change / get updated. How can I change the size of this svg via css? Thanks.

```css
svg {
  font-size: 300px;
}

svg > circle {
  fill: red;
}

svg > path {
  fill: orange;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
  <path d="M0,50 a1,1 0 0,0 100,0" />
</svg>
```

Comment: You can try viewbox and CSS. See this article - https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach:
You set the viewBox attribute on the SVG so that it will scale to its container. Then you set the width of that container in *em's*. This means it will scale with the font size you set on the container.

```css
svg>circle {
  fill: red;
}

svg>path {
  fill: orange;
}

.svg-container {
  font-size: 300px;
  width: 4em;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.alpha {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.beta {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.gamma {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-container alpha">
  10px
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
      <path d="M0,50 a1,1 0 0,0 100,0" />
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="svg-container beta">
  20px
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
      <path d="M0,50 a1,1 0 0,0 100,0" />
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="svg-container gamma">
  100px
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
      <path d="M0,50 a1,1 0 0,0 100,0" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You want to use the `scale` command.  From [CanIUse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=transform%3A%20scale), it looks like this works everywhere except for IE11.

```css
svg {
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: scale(3);
}

svg > circle {
  fill: red;
}

svg > path {
  fill: orange;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
  <path d="M0,50 a1,1 0 0,0 100,0" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This has a disadvantage: Quote from the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering): **"Transformations do affect the visual rendering, but have no affect on the CSS layout other than affecting overflow."** That means if the `<svg>` (an inline element) is used for example in the middle of text, text following after a circle will be positioned as if the circle had not been enlarged, and might disappear below the circle.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this code will help you.

```css
svg {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px
}

#semi-circle1 {
  fill: red;
}

#semi-circle2 {
  fill: orange;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="cut-off-top">
      <rect x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="cut-off-bottom">
      <rect x="0%" y="50%" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle id="semi-circle1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="red" clip-path="url(#cut-off-top)" />
  <circle id="semi-circle2" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="orange" clip-path="url(#cut-off-bottom)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [viewbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox). The value of the viewBox attribute is a list of four numbers: min-x, min-y, width and height. This way you can change the size by css too.

```css
svg {
  width: 300px;/*Overwrites the width in the svg viewbox*/
  height: 300px;/*Overwrites the height in the svg viewbox*/
}

svg > circle {
  fill: red;
}

svg > path {
  fill: orange;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100"> <!-- Width 100px, height 100px -->
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
  <path d="M0,50 a1,1 0 0,0 100,0" />
</svg>
```